# ¿Tiene el adjetivo "petiso" una connotación negativa?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, argentina

En una serie argentina que vi en YouTube escuché la palabra *petiso* usada para referirse a una persona de baja estatura. En un principio pensé que sería una palabra de argot, pero por curiosidad [eencontré su significado en la RAE](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?id=lLo8Q58MiDXX2EsQkn7p).

Me gustaría saber si esta palabra tiene connotaciones negativas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sí**, tiene connotación negativa.

En Chile (y, según tu ejemplo, también en Argentina) es una de esas palabras en las que la carga afectiva generalmente supera en relevancia al significado literal. Se las puede usar para molestar u ofender, pero también para expresar cariño en ciertos contextos. Podría ser equivalente a *enano* en el caso de la estatura o *cerdo* para alguien gordo.

La palabra viene del francés *petit* ("pequeño"), pero originalmente se refería a un tipo de caballo.

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración :)